# Initializer list with a variable length defined vector

Tags: c++, variables, vector, constructor, initialization

```
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class NumArray 
{
    public:
        NumArray(vector<int>& nums)
            : nums(nums)
            , length(nums.size())
        {
            vector< vector<int> > tmp(length, vector<int> (length, NULL));
            this->lookup = tmp;
        }

    private:
        vector<int>& nums;
        vector< vector<int> > lookup;
        int length;
};
```

I got an inefficient way to initialize the vector *lookup* by constructing vector *tmp* first, but there should be a method initialize *lookup* through initializer list explicitly. Like

```
public:
    NumArray(vector<int>& nums)
        : nums(nums)
        , length(nums.size())
        , lookup(length, vector<int> (length, NULL))
    {

    }
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work with the initializer list? What problems do you have?

Comment: And note that `NULL` is a C backward compatibility macro for null *pointers*, not null values (which doesn't exist in C++). If you want default-constructed or initialized values, don't pass the second argument to the `std::vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Also note that a vector size can never be negative, and one should be using `size_t` for storing it. And that the vector you pass for `nums` need to stay alive at least as long as the `NumArray` object you create (otherwise the `nums` reference becomes invalid).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your helpful advice! This error occurs due to the order of initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing works fine, [you're just not doing it right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) (emphasis mine):

> **The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant**: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1. If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual bases are initialized in the order in which they appear in depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
> 2. Then, direct bases are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
> 3. Then, **non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition**.
> 4. Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

This means that in your case:

```
private:
    vector<int>& nums;
    vector< vector<int> > lookup;
    int length;
```

`lookup` is initialized before `length`, and as such, `length` may not appear in the `lookup` constructor.

Swap the declarations of the two to fix the issue, or for a more reliable solution, do not use members in member initializer lists at all. This will work just as well, without potentially causing what you are experiencing right now.

```
NumArray(vector<int>& nums)
        : nums(nums)
        , length(nums.size())
        , lookup(nums.size(), vector<int> (nums.size(), NULL)) {} // `length` does not need to be used at all
```